# MQTT messages - How to parse

Tags: elasticsearch

New user as of a few days ago.  Just got Kibana, Elasticsearch, Logstash,  and 2 filebeats running (Log and MQTT) Thanks to all the supporters.

I'm able to get the MQTT messages from filebeat and seen in Kibana.

Next questions that I cannot get - Due to concepts, or lack of flow knowledge.

1. When I receive MQTT messages, they are sent to a specific topic but the message may have lots of different data in it.   How can I extra just the information I want and graph that?  Eg, in the message below from a 4-channel sonoff switch, there is "POWER1":"OFF".   and then Power2, power3, power4.  I'd like to graph those.   Is this a filebeat processor, a logstash processor, a splitter?

{"Time":"2024-01-23T18:31:38","Uptime":"0T09:35:09","UptimeSec":34509,"Heap":23,"SleepMode":"Dynamic","Sleep":50,"LoadAvg":19,"MqttCount":5,"POWER1":"OFF","POWER2":"ON","POWER3":"OFF","POWER4":"OFF","Wifi":{"AP":1,"SSId":"MYSSID","BSSId":"EA:CB:BC:50:04:0C","Channel":11,"Mode":"11n","RSSI":42,"Signal":-79,"LinkCount":1,"Downtime":"0T00:00:03"}}

2. How do I know if the events are coming through logstash? I thought I set everything up but it looks like my filebeat events may be going directly to Elasticsearch and thus I cannot use logstash filters? Screeenshot of the event in #1

Followed multiple docs to get setup and it's work.
However, I don't where to go next for parsing MQTT

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question:
There is no trace of official input mqtt plugin in logstash, but you can easily get messages using tcp plugin for exemple.
Once Logstash receives the data you can parse them using the [json filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html).

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
 }
```

For your second question, you can simply add a tag to every entry going throu Logstash using [the filter mutate and add_tag](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_tag):

```
filter {
    mutate {
        add_tag => [ "logstash_parsed" ]
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm using MQTT into filebeat.   That was supposed to feed to feed into logstash but I think i'm not doing it properly because the message seems to show up as filebeat directly.

https://ibb.co/tsCdYSB

Per this screenshot

I'd have thought that anyone who tried to use filebeat to bring in MQTT would have this same issue of lots of data into a single message and have to parse it somehow?

As you mentioned, the filter mutate and add tag,  but that doesn't allow me to parse the MQTT message and pull out data right?

Comment: I'm 2 days into this adventure and a bit over my skies at hte moment.  Not knowing if I am doing things right